# Incompatible library version: AwaitKit requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libswiftCore.dylib provides version 0.0.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My app has been running on simulator perfectly fine. I tried to load it on my device (iPhone XS, iOS 12.1.2), and a window popped up in Xcode saying Could not launch "MyApp", internal error.

I looked at the device logs from Window > Devices and Simulators and I see a crash log from my app. In the logs, I see a message:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Description: DYLD, Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib | Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FFBD3A48-511D-48E6-A14B-C8207A7F2DCA/HackerNews.app/Frameworks/AwaitKit.framework/AwaitKit | Reason: Incompatible library version: AwaitKit requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libswiftCore.dylib provides version 0.0.0
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

I'm not sure why the Swift core lib version would be 0.0.0, something seems very off here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find out that I was using the wrong toolchain, I needed to be using the Xcode one instead of the Swift 4.2 one.

Answer (score 4):

Use multiple Swift toolchain.

Every time we update Swift Version, usually the open source code have not been updated and get matched.

So use multiple Swift toolchain to use the Swift of older version. Or wait the open source code get updated.

---

To switch back,

firstly , go to [swift.org](https://swift.org/)

Then, Download the older Swift version

[image: 00]
install package

[image: 11]

switch the Swift version in Toolchains

[image: 22]

or switch the Swift version in Preference / Components

[image: 33]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but then started encountering other errors because Swift 4.0.3 does not support Xcode 10. However this led me to the solution, which was that I needed to use the Xcode 10 framework, not the Swift 4.2 Release which I was using.